# how to move 3 a tags under another element (h1 tag)

Tags: jquery, html

I have the html like this :

```
<a class="test" href="11"></a>
<a class="test" href="12"></a>
<a class="test" href="13"></a>
<p> bla bla bla goes here  </p>
<h1> Awesome Title is here</h1>
```

this is what I tried and didn't work for me:

```
<script>

jQuery('.test').prepend( jQuery('h1') );

</script>
```

I am trying to use jQuery to move the 3 a tags UNDER the h1 tag.
any ideas?  :) thank you!!

(please dont suggest any other way to do it I want to do it in jquery )

Comment: By "under" do you mean after?

Comment: And what happens to the `<p>`?

Comment: yes after sorry. the p and h tag stay in their spot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're looking to move the links to come after the `<h1>`, then you can either use:

```
jQuery('.test').insertAfter( jQuery('h1') );
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/WTa9F/)**

**Or**

```
jQuery('h1').after( jQuery('.test') );
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/sKw77/)**